# How to parse nested JSON data structure in C#

Tags: c#, json, nested

I am trying to parse the following JSON data structure:

```
{
    Command: "somecommand", 
    ContractNo: "11111111", 
    DocsFiles:  [{DocumentID: "01", Files: [{DocKey: "Key01", PrimKey: "PKey01"}, 
                                          {DocKey: "Key01", PrimKey: "PKey02"}],
                {DocumentID: "02", Files: [{DocKey: "Key02", PrimKey: "PKey03"}, 
                                          {DocKey: "Key02", PrimKey: "PKey04"}]]
}
```

This is a code:

```
public class Result
{
    public string DocumentID {get; set;}
    public List<Files> FilesList {get; set;}

    public class Files
    {
        public string DocKey {get; set;}
        public string PrimKey {get; set;}
    }
}


private void shareDocumentFiles(RequestContext pContext)
{   
    try
    {
        string vContractNo = pContext.JsonParameters["ContractNo"].ToString();

        var vFiles = pContext.JsonParameters["DocsFiles"].ToString();

        var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Result>>(vFiles);

        ...
```

I can get "DocumentID" value, but cannot get "DocKey", or "PrimKey" values.

```
var DocID = results[0].DocumentID;
```

Please help to solve this.

Comment: You have a problem with your JSON, and likely with your code.  The way I read your JSON is that doc 01 is associated with PrimKey 01 and 02.  In that case, your "Files:" object should contain an array of DocKey/PrimKey pairs (i.e., the two DocKey/PrimKey objects should be within square brackets (`[]`).  If you do that, then you need to change your C# to match

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the JSON, yes Files object contains an array of DocKey/PrimKey

Comment: your code will work just fine, if you change just ``public List<Files> FilesList {get; set;}``to ``public List<Files> Files{get; set;}`` or use annotation for ``FilesList`` property like ``[JsonProperty(PropertyName="Files")]``. because ``FilesList `` not match any property in your json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your JSON to look like:

```
{
  "Command": "somecommand",
  "ContractNo": "11111111",
  "DocsFiles": [
    {
      "DocumentID": "01",
      "Files": [
        {
          "DocKey": "Key01",
          "PrimKey": "PKey01"
        },
        {
          "DocKey": "Key01",
          "PrimKey": "PKey02"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "DocumentID": "02",
      "Files": [
        {
          "DocKey": "Key02",
          "PrimKey": "PKey03"
        },
        {
          "DocKey": "Key02",
          "PrimKey": "PKey04"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I created three simple matching classes:

```
public class InputClass
{
    public string Command { get; set; }
    public string ContractNo { get; set; }
    public List<DocFile> DocFiles { get; set; }
}

public class DocFile
{
    public string DocumentID { get; set;}
    public List<FileInfo> Files { get; set; }
}
public class FileInfo
{
    public string DocFile { get; set;}
    public string PrimKey { get; set; }
}
```

and then I read the contents of the JSON and deserialized it using:

```
 var fileContents = File.ReadAllText("DocFiles.json");
 var docFiles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DocFile>(fileContents);
```

and it works like a charm.  Note that your `DocFiles` is a collection, as is the `DocKey`/`PrimKey` pair.

If your contract numbers and Document IDs are necessarily always numeric, you may want to type them as integers rather than strings (in which case, they'd loose the quotes in the JSON)